# How does Pentaho Data Integration connect to Microsoft Dataverse?

Tags: integration, pentaho, data-warehouse, dataverse

We are using Dynamics 365 with Microsoft's Dataverse platform. I want to use How does Pentaho Data Integration to connect to the data platform to build DWH. Do you have any experience or help me how to make Pentaho Data Integration connect to Dataverse?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything Pentaho-specific, but the recommended way to get Dataverse data out for analytics is with Synapse Link for Dataverse, which can [replicate your Dataverse data to an open Data Lake in Delta format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/azure-synapse-link-delta-lake).

From there you can use it in any tool that can read Delta/parquet files.

Answer (score 0):

For an export we are using standard functionality to push it from dynamics into azure data lake, and from there we load it into PDI

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CData JDBC Driver for Microsoft Dataverse to access live data from dashboards and reports in Pentaho1.

Another option is you can use Synapse Link for Dataverse to replicate your Dataverse data to an open Data Lake in Delta format and then use any tool that can read Delta/parquet files2.